# Condition to point out Error in line formatting not being met

Tags: java, string, format, string-formatting

I have a program which reads a file and enforces a certain format in every line. If a line has a format error, it prints a line below it indicating which error it was.

For each line, From column 1 to 13 and 77 to 80, no formatting rules are enforced, so I don't care about dots in these columns.

For the case of the dot character, every dot must not be preceded by white space, and it must be followed by white space.

I have a condition to check for this, and at a glance it seems right, but it's still not catching errors in dot formatting.

```
public static boolean checkLineFormatErrors(String line){
int errorCount;
if(line.contains(".")){ 
                        errorCount = 0;
                        char[] charArr = line.toCharArray();
                        boolean problemWithDot = false;
                        for(int i = 0; i < charArr.length;i++){
                                if(i < charArr.length - 1 
                        && i > 12 && i < 76 
                        && charArr[i] == '.' && (charArr[i-1] == ' ' || charArr[i+1] != ' ')){
                                    problemWithDot = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        if(problemWithDot){
                            errorMessage = "One or more dots do not follow the line format for this file.";
                            errorCount++;
                            if(errorCount > 1){
                                System.out.println(errorMessage);
                            } 
                            else{
                                System.out.println(line + errorMessage);
                            }
                        }
                    }
return problemWithDot
}
```

All of my other methods for catching errors in format for other symbols work, it's only the dot one that doesn't.

For example

```
00012       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION .
00013       DATA DIVISION.
00014       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
00015        77 NUMERO1 PIC 9(2) VALUE ZEROS .
```

Line 12 and 15 should have an error message below them, because their final dot is preceded by a space.

(If you're wondering "Hey isn't that last bit of code Cobol?? Why are you not adding a cobol tag?" Yes those last lines are cobol! This is not a cobol issue because the program for checking the errors is made in Java only. Cobol is only a way to test the file to enforce its rules.)

Comment: If a dot is at the end of the line, it will be at `i == charArray.length - 1`; your condition of `i < charArray.length - 1` excludes that case, so dots at the end of the line (which it would appear all of yours are) are never checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By fixing your loop, it works, the main problem being with

```
i < charArr.length - 1
```

when the `dot` is at the end

```
for(int i = 12; i < charArr.length && i < 76;i++)
{
    if(charArr[i] == '.' && (charArr[i-1] == ' ' || 
                            charArr[Math.min(charArr.length -1, i+1)] != ' '))
   {
        problemWithDot = true;
        break;
   }
}
```

**note**

`charArr[i+1] != ' '` is likely to cause problem so check that `i + 1` does not exceed the array length.

Comment: I tried to implement this, but now every line with a dot is being flagged as having an error. I believe that the issue is that I'm now saying that the final dot HAS to be followed by a space and apparently none of my dots are. So I tried to change it to be either the dot is not preceded by a space OR the dot is not followed by either a space or a newline. Its still flagging every line with a dot as wrong.

`charArr[i] == '.' && (charArr[i-1] == ' ' || (charArr[Math.min(charArr.length -1, i+1)] != ' ' && (charArr[Math.min(charArr.length -1, i+1)] != '\n')))`

Comment: I managed to solve it by changing the last `charArr[Math.min(charArr.length -1, i+1)] != '\n'` to `charArr[Math.min(charArr.length -1, i+1)] != '.'`